# Pip install doesn't checkout correct branch

Tags: python, git, ubuntu, pip, puppet

Here is the command I am running from puppet:

```
venv/bin/pip install -e git+https://blablabla.com/git/myproject.git@develop#egg=myproject
```

Which should install the develop branch. Instead it installs no branch. When I go to venv/src/myproject and do git branch I see:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/usr/service/myproject/venv/src/myproject$ git branch
* (no branch)
  master
```

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. What could be the problem?

Comment: You get master because it's set as the default branch when you clone.  It appears you aren't on a branch because pip is doing a `git checkout origin/develop`... which leaves you in a detached HEAD state.  I don't believe pip supports anything else, at the moment.